# How to extract multiple values from a perl hashref?

Tags: perl, hashref

How can I unpack a Perl hashref into multiple named scalar variables?

I've seen it done but can't seem to make it work.

Assuming the `$hashref` as given, and the definition of `$arg1` to `$arg3`, here's my attempt:

```
my $hashref = { arg1 => 'val1', arg2 => 'val2', arg3 => 'val3',};
my ($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) = @{%$hashref}[qw(arg1 arg2 arg3)];
```

Comment: Apparently I asked the same question 7 years ago - here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this

```
my ($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) = @{$hashref}{qw(arg1 arg2 arg3)};
```

Which is a hash slice against a hash ref

Comment: perfect. Accepted.